# Devstack install Controller node

Tags: devstack

I'm going through the devstack tutorial and I'm trying to setup the Controller Node [as explained in the instruction](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/guides/multinode-lab.html#configure-cluster-controller). Unfortinately, I'm getting the following error when running `for i in` seq 2 10`; do /opt/stack/nova/bin/nova-manage fixed reserve 10.4.128.$i; done` :

```
stack@ubuntu-server:~/devstack$ for i in `seq 2 10`; do /opt/stack/nova/bin/nova-manage fixed 
reserve 10.4.128.$i; done
bash: /opt/stack/nova/bin/nova-manage: No such file or directory
bash: /opt/stack/nova/bin/nova-manage: No such file or directory
bash: /opt/stack/nova/bin/nova-manage: No such file or directory
bash: /opt/stack/nova/bin/nova-manage: No such file or directory
bash: /opt/stack/nova/bin/nova-manage: No such file or directory
bash: /opt/stack/nova/bin/nova-manage: No such file or directory
bash: /opt/stack/nova/bin/nova-manage: No such file or directory
bash: /opt/stack/nova/bin/nova-manage: No such file or directory
bash: /opt/stack/nova/bin/nova-manage: No such file or directory
```

Perhaps someone can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file `nova-mange` is actually in `/usr/local/bin/nova-manage`